Unity AddCrypto in CryptoText || 3D GAME Unity
https://i.imgur.com/i5saoOs.mp4
The idea of this game, it's to have a basic graphic card on the pc. When the player press on Pc, it shows a Panel where it shows some information about the mining power of that graphic card and the button ''Start'' for start mining and ''CryptoText'' it's updated. The player can buy more rigs from StorePanel, when the rig it's shown in the scene, the player can touch it to start mining also but with different mining power and need to update ''CryptoText'' like acumulate, but you can see in the video how it's work, in the same ''Crypto Text'', but not acumulate. Reference are sets and the rigs are prefabs in Assets folder.
If someone can help me, I will appreciate it a lot!
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class UIController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject infoPanel;
    public CryptoMining cryptoMining;
    public Button mineButton;
    public Text moneyText;
    public Text cryptoText;
    private Animator infoPanelAnimator;
    public ElectricityManager electricityManager; // Referință la scriptul ElectricityManager

    private float playerMoney = 123250f;
    private float cryptoAmount = 0f;

    void Start()
    {
        infoPanelAnimator = infoPanel.GetComponent<Animator>();
        UpdateMoneyText();
        UpdateCryptoText();
    }

    public void OnMineButtonClicked()
    {
        cryptoMining.StartMining();
        mineButton.interactable = false;
    }

    public void OnCloseButtonClicked()
    {
        infoPanelAnimator.SetTrigger("Hide");
    }

    public void ShowInfoPanel()
    {
        infoPanel.transform.localScale = Vector3.zero;
        infoPanelAnimator.SetTrigger("Show");
        mineButton.interactable = true;
    }

    private void UpdateMoneyText()
    {
        if (moneyText != null)
        {
            moneyText.text = "Money: " + playerMoney.ToString("F2");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("moneyText reference is not set in the Inspector.");
        }
    }

    private void UpdateCryptoText()
    {
        if (cryptoText != null)
        {
            cryptoText.text = "Crypto: " + cryptoAmount.ToString("F6");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("cryptoText reference is not set in the Inspector.");
        }
    }

    
    public void AddCrypto(float amount)
    {
        cryptoAmount += amount;
        UpdateCryptoText();
    }

    public void AddMoney(float amount)
    {
        playerMoney += amount;
        UpdateMoneyText();
    }

    public void SpendMoney(float amount)
    {
        if (playerMoney >= amount)
        {
            playerMoney -= amount;
            UpdateMoneyText();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Not enough money to complete the transaction.");
        }
    }



    public void SpendCrypto(float amount)
    {
        if (cryptoAmount >= amount)
        {
            cryptoAmount -= amount;
            UpdateCryptoText();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Not enough crypto to complete the transaction.");
        }
    }

    
    public float GetPlayerMoney()
    {
        return playerMoney;
    }

    public float GetCryptoAmount()
    {
        return cryptoAmount;
    }
}


using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MiningRig : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float miningPower; // Puterea de minare specifică rig-ului
    public float miningInterval; // Intervalul de timp pentru minare
    public float miningRate = 0.0005f;
    public UIController uiController;
    private MiningManager miningManager;
    public CryptoMining cryptoMining;
    private bool isMining = false;

    void Start()
    {
        if (miningManager == null)
        {
            miningManager = FindObjectOfType<MiningManager>();
            if(miningManager == null)
            {
                Debug.LogError("mining manager not found in");
            }
        }

        // Ne asigurăm că obiectul are un BoxCollider
        if (GetComponent<BoxCollider>() == null)
        {
            gameObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
        }

        // Încercăm să găsim UIController dacă nu este setat
        if (uiController == null)
        {
            uiController = FindObjectOfType<UIController>();
            if (uiController == null)
            {
                Debug.LogError("UIController not found in the scene. Please assign it in the inspector.");
            }
        }
    }

    
    public void SetMiningPower(float power)
    {
        miningPower = power;
    }

    public void SetMiningInterval(float interval)
    {
        miningInterval = interval;
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if (!isMining)
        {
            StartMining();
        }
    }

    void StartMining()
    {
        if (!isMining)
        {
            isMining = true;
            InvokeRepeating("MineCrypto", 0f, 1f);
            Debug.Log("Mining rig started");
        }
    }

    


    void MineCrypto()
    {
        if (MiningManager.Instance == null)
        {
            
            Debug.LogError("MiningManager instance not found. Please ensure it exists in the scene.");
            return;
        }

        if (uiController == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("UIController reference is missing. Please assign it in the inspector or ensure it exists in the scene.");
            return;
        }

        float minedAmount = miningRate * MiningManager.Instance.GetGlobalMiningRateFactor();
        uiController.AddCrypto(minedAmount);
        Debug.Log("Mining rig mined: " + minedAmount);
    }
    public void StopMining()
    {
        isMining = false;
    }
}

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class CryptoMining : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text cryptoText;
    public float miningInterval = 3f;
    public float miningRate = 0.134134f;
    public float cryptoValue = 0.01f;
    public UIController uiController;

    private float cryptoAmount = 0f;
    private bool isMining = false;
    public float miningPower = 0.1f;
    private float originalMiningPower;
    private float globalMiningRateFactor = 1f;
    public float baseMiningRate = 0.001753f;
    

    void Start()
    {
        
        originalMiningPower = miningPower;
        
        UpdateCryptoText();
    }

    public void StartMining()
    {
        if (!isMining)
        {
            isMining = true;
            InvokeRepeating("MineCrypto", 0f, miningInterval);
        }
    }

    void MineCrypto()
    {
        cryptoAmount += miningRate * miningPower;
        UpdateCryptoText();
        if (uiController != null)
        {
            uiController.AddMoney(miningRate * miningPower * cryptoValue);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("UIController reference is not set in the CryptoMining script.");
        }
    }

     public void SetMiningEfficiency(float efficiency)
    {
        globalMiningRateFactor = efficiency;
    }

    public void ReduceMiningEfficiency(float factor)
    {
        miningPower = originalMiningPower * factor;
        Debug.Log($"Mining efficiency reduced. New mining power: {miningPower}");
    }

    // Adăugat metoda GetBaseMiningRate pentru a obține rata de minare de bază
public float GetBaseMiningRate()
{
    return baseMiningRate;
}


    public float GetGlobalMiningRateFactor()
    {
        return globalMiningRateFactor;
    }

    public void ResetMiningEfficiency()
    {
        miningPower = originalMiningPower;
        Debug.Log($"Mining efficiency reset. Mining power: {miningPower}");
    }

    private void UpdateCryptoText()
    {
        if (cryptoText != null)
        {
            cryptoText.text = $"Crypto: {cryptoAmount:F6}";
        }
    }
}

I try to do a 3D game that simulate somehow real life mining and I implement a store where the player can buy some new rigs for more crypto, but the value is put also in ''CryptoText'' but in different way, you can see that in that video that is updated the value separated.
